# Is there any Flex 4 data visualization for analysis of relational data (link-based phenomena)?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I have been goggling a lot to find anything that can help me with link-based data visualization in Flex 4. something like below screen shoot (made using [Ravis](http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/wiki/RaVis)).

[image]

Where user can drag these nodes, without removing the links and on double click of any node we can set some properties for that particular node.

I found this [Ravis (Birdeye)](http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/wiki/RaVis), but not much of examples and support is available for that. I was wondering is there any thing already present in Flex 4 or anything that might help?

Thanks

Comment: Check this out might be a decent starting point: http://flare.prefuse.org/demo or else check out the drag and drop examples, then you just have to keep track of edges made between two objects and draw with lineTo between them http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64595-7fed.html

Comment: @shaunhusain: Thanks, I tried this in Flex 3, works good but the only problem is maintaining the edges (lineTo), that is why I wanted if there is anything which would be much simpler present in Flex 4 or may be some framework with good support or examples.

Comment: I don't really know much about it. But i found this a while ago: http://lab.kapit.fr/demo/diagrammer/prod/index.html#

Comment: @Sebastian: Looks good, trying to find editing properties for any node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the components from [Kap IT Lab](http://lab.kapit.fr/) They have been around for a long time, and you can test them for free. They also have a free community edition, which may suit your needs.
I am not associated to them in any way. You can see demos of their components in the Tour de Flex application.

Comment: Sebastian also mentioned the same thing, i am taking a look into it. Thanks. More suggestions are also welcome :)